# Why does a multi-line file not compare equal to itself?

Tags: powershell

When I use `gc` (`get-content`) on the same file twice, and compare the strings using `-eq`, why does it compare unequal?

```
$f = "C:\temp\test.txt"
echo Hello > $f
echo World >>$f # works if I uncomment this line

gc $f

# get the contents of the file twice and compare it to itself.
if ((gc $f) -eq (gc $f)) {
    Write-Host "Hooray! The file is the same as itself."
} else {
    Write-Host "Boo."
}
```

Prints `Boo.`, unless I comment out the 3rd line - the problem only seems to occur with multiline files.

(obviously in reality I wouldn't compare the file to itself, in real life I'm comparing two files that *might* have identical content).

I'm running powershell 2.0.

Comment: Note to self: [RTFM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849787.aspx)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will work if the file has only one line, but will fail if there are multiple lines because of the way -eq works as an array operator.  For it to work as expected you need to compare both as scalar (single item) objects.  One way to do this is to add the -Raw switch to Get-Content if you've got V3 or better.

```
if ((gc $f -raw) -eq (gc $f -raw))
```

That will read the entire file as a single, multi-line string.

To accomplish the same in V2:

```
if ([io.file]::ReadAllText($f)) -eq ([io.file]::ReadAllText($f))
```

or

```
if ([string](gc $f) -eq [string](gc $f))
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise it was returning an array. Thanks! is there a ps 2.0 equivalent?